# How to use reusable controller methods in Rails?

Tags: ruby-on-rails, ruby

I'm relatively new to Rails and am working on creating a simple user authentication system to get to grips with how Rails works.

I'm currently at the point where I'd like to create some methods that I can use in my controllers like so:

```
is_logged? # => true
```

and

```
current_user_id # => 6
```

These would be used to interact with sessions, mainly so I'm not repeating myself in the controller.

Where would I define these functions and how would I include them in a controller?

Thanks a lot in advance for any help.

Answer (score 7, accepted):

**Method 1**

You can define these method in helper files, inside `app/helpers/my_module.rb`. You can create a module there, put all the methods inside of it, and then include the modules in your control to use these method.

```
module MyMoule
  def is_logged?
    ...
  end
end
```

Then in you class include the module

```
class MyClassController < ApplicationController
  include MyModule

  def my_method
    #Use it like this
    logged_in = MyModule.is_logged?
  end
end
```

**Method 2**

If you using session related stuff you can always put them inside `application_controller.rb`. And since all your controller will inherit `ApplicationController` the methods will be available to you.

```
class ApplicationController < ActionController::Base
  def is_logged?
    ...
  end
end
```

In your other controller you can use them directly.

```
class MyClassController < ApplicationController
  def my_method
    logged_in = is_logged?
  end
end
```